# Average time from each user?

Tags: sql

The below query im getting the average time of the difference of two dates from a specific
time.This is for all the records from the table.
I would like to get the average time from each user_id.

```
create table agentdispo
(callstartdt datetime, 
callenddt datetime,
user_id varchar(25)
)

SELECT AVG(average_time) as average_time
FROM (SELECT cast(convert (datetime,DateDiff(MINUTE,CallStartDt,CallEndDt))as float) as average_time 
      FROM AgentDispo
      where CALLSTARTDT between '2015-01-05' and '2015-01-31'
) as SubQuery
```

How can I get the average time from each user_id from that callstartdt dates?

Comment: Which part of SQL allows you to perform aggregations for each value in one (or more) columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you performing a subquery?

```
SELECT user_id, AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, callstartdt, callenddt)) as average_time
FROM AgentDispo
WHERE callstartdt between '2015-01-05' and '2015-01-31'
GROUP BY user_id;
```

I believe this will work as expected.  timestampdiff gets the difference between two datetime fields in the units specified.  This will show the average of seconds.

The group by is used to specify for each user.

In regards to your query, you are also specifying the alias **average_time twice**, once in the subquery and once in the main query.  I think that is going to cause problems for you.  Even if it works, it is messy, you always should use a unique alias.

Comment: Oh my fault.  I thought this was MySQL.  Which DBMS are you using?  It is usually good to specify that when asking questions.

Comment: sql 2012, i change it to DateDiff and it work , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a `group by for USER_ID` along with your aggregation for AVG time

```
SELECT AVG(average_time) as average_time, user_id
FROM (SELECT cast(convert (datetime,DateDiff(MINUTE,CallStartDt,CallEndDt))as float) as average_time 
          FROM AgentDispo
          where CALLSTARTDT between '2015-01-05' and '2015-01-31'
    ) as SubQuery
GROUP BY user_id
```